# DialogFlow - 1 word trigger 2 entities

Tags: dialogflow-es

For my project I need to trigger 2 entities by one word. I have two entities with list of restaurant types the **restaurant_type_id** and **restaurant_type**. In the responses I am using **$restaurant_type**, but I need also to trigger the **id** of the restaurant type that is inside **restaurant_type_id**.

In the example below you can see that only one of the entities is triggered.

[image]

Is there a way to do that or that is not possible? I have tried looking for more information, but couldn't find anything in the DialogFlow Docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting the id as well as the name is by asking the Dialogflow to send the original value along with the resolved one.

To do this, you can create one single entity like below,
[image]

Next in the intent section under the parameter, you can tell the Dialogflow to send both the original and resolved data.[image]

Now you have both the id and name.

Comment: Wow, that's it... You are a lifesaver! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In order to work the above answer, you will have to follow this rule. Otherwise, it won't recognise.

[image]

Comment: Look at my example. both entities have italian as a synonym. The problem is that it matched only one of the entities. either first on or second one but never both in the same time, which is my original question

Comment: I was referring to the answer given by shradha. For example, 103 should be a synonym of itself to work.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now. Thanks @Ershadi